# How to tracing client IP from the original request in C# MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, ip

I created 3 projects WebSite, WebApi and CoreAuthWebApi.  They all interact with each other.

Here is the request flow:

WebSite --> WebApi --> CoreAuthWebApi 
CoreAuthWebApi --> WebApi --> WebSite

What is the best way for CoreAuthWebApi to get the WebSite Client IP without IP spoofing?

Comment: You would need to pass it through...

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way for CoreAuthWebApi to get the WebSite Client IP without IP spoofing?

If the call is made on behalf of the web site, the API has no way of knowing the IP of the user agent unless you pass it as parameter. Remember the client of the API in this case is the IP of the server where the website is hosted.

Since the website knows the IP of the user agent it can pass it to the API as parameter.